# Hide footer div while swiping down /scrolling down the app in cordova / phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to hide the footer div while scrolling down but I'm unable to do it.

I'm using the following code,where the swipe down event listener is not working and I don't know whether this code works without any plugins, if Cordova needs plugins for detecting scrolls means please suggest me the plugins.

**jquery**

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener('swipedown', sdown, false);
}
function sdown()
{
    $('.footer').fadeout();
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of your HTML? How do you position the footer div... is it absolute element, flexbox or you have a lot of content?

Comment: @XristoEftimov, i found that the actual problem is swipedown eventlistener is not working, please help me with that